# How to hide AspxTextBox?

Tags: asp.net

On a radio button checked event, I hide the div by

```
document.getElementById("AltYukleniciDiv").style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

But, when I use it for an aspxTextBox, it doesn't hide it. Or when I use the ClientInstanceName instead of document.getElementById("  ")

```
UnvanText.SetVisible(false);    this didn't work either. UnvanText is ClientInsanceName.
```

javascript crashes there. I put an allert after that and it never shows it. I have to do it because I hide a div, including everything in it, but it still shows the textboxes that has validation. I don't know how it is possible. Can you tell me a way to hide them all? It used to hide the div with all of its contents before I make some validation settings.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, sorry.

Comment: Switch over to .NET MVC and be free with those generated ids + having clean html!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a CssClass attribute to that text box then use it to find the element and hide it.

You can consider using jQuery, so you need to write a single line of code:

```
$(".MyHideClass").hide();
```

or set attribute style display:none

I can advice using Firebug (FF Extension) for debugging javascript

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like asp.net is being 'helpful' and changing the IDs of your elements.

Give the text box the attribute `ClientIdMode="Static"`, and it might fix it.